# extensions problem with multi model not working

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

TransformationTool extension does not work when loading multiple models. It may also be due to the codes I wrote due to the version change.

**Viewer.js**

```
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv, {
    extensions: [
      "Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.TransformTool",
      "Autodesk.DocumentBrowser",
      "TransformationExtension",
    ],
  });

  viewer.loadModel('./wraith.glb', { options2 }, wraith, (err) => console.error(err));
  viewer.loadModel("./wraith.glb", { options2 }, wraith2, (err) =>console.error(err));
  viewer.loadModel("./sample_revit_big.glb", (model) => { item = model; });
```

I think there is an error in the code writing here in the extension file, thank you very much if you help.

**TransformationTool**

```
                viewer.addEventListener(
                    Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT,
                    onCameraChanged);

                event.fragIdsArray.forEach(function (fragId) {

                    var fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(
                        viewer.model,
                        fragId);




        this.getTransformMap = function() {

            var transformMap = {};

            for(var fragId in _modifiedFragIdMap){

                var fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(
                    viewer.model,
                    fragId);

                fragProxy.getAnimTransform();

                transformMap[fragId] = {
                    position: fragProxy.position
                };

                fragProxy = null;
            }

            return transformMap;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right - the extension has been implemented for single-model scenarios only. I'd suggest to look for other examples of "transform" extensions online as some of them could support multi-model scenarios as well, or to modify the extension you're using. The modifications will require some effort but overall it should be doable. For example, instead of relying on `viewer.model` (reference to the last loaded model) you would have to iterate over all loaded models using `viewer.getVisibleModels()`.